# Issues with Java Web Start and Safari

Tags: java, safari, java-web-start

I have a Java webstart application, fully signed, and it has been deployed live for over a year now.  We have never been able to get it to work with Safari for some reason.  Actually, I have not been able to get any [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) application working with Safari.

Internet searches are spotty and I can’t seem to nail down why Safari has issues with web start.

**EDIT**

Here is the java stack trace from the Java console in Safari. Please understand that the Java Web Start application works correctly without any issues in Firefox, IE, Chrome, etc.

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_29
Using JRE version 1.6.0_29-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\strings




----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to 
----------------------------------------------------

load: class com.novel.tech1.client.JAWSApplication not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.novel.tech1.client.JAWSApplication 
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail *how* it doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the limitations mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#117), I've avoided the built-in AppletViewer of Java Web Start. As an alternative, consider the hybrid applet/application approach shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway), which works in Safari, *et al*. Note that the request for access to your computer can be safely denied, as the applet runs correctly in the sandbox.

Comment: I was about to update that 1st link to the [Java 7 docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/faq.html#35)(1) hoping they might have mentioned the ability to use JWS to deploy ***embedded*** applets using the plug-in 2 architecture JRE.  But they didn't, so I decided to leave the answer as-is.  1) turns out it has been moved out of the 'docs by version' path, actually..